# variables need to wrapped as a string

Tags: php, mysql

I have written this query,

```
    $sql = "SELECT `candidates`.`candidate_id`, `candidates`.`first_name`, `candidates`.`surname`, `candidates`.`DOB`, `candidates`.`gender`, DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y') - DATE_FORMAT(`candidates`.`DOB`, '%Y') - (DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '00-%m-%d') < DATE_FORMAT(`candidates`.`DOB`, '00-%m-%d')) AS `age`, `candidates`.`talent`, `candidates`.`location`, `candidates`.`availability`, `candidate_assets`.`url`, `candidate_assets`.`asset_size`
            FROM `candidates`
            LEFT JOIN `candidate_assets` ON `candidate_assets`.`candidates_candidate_id` = `candidates`.`candidate_id`
            WHERE `candidates`.`availability` = 'yes'";

            if(isset($type)) {
                $sql .= ' AND candidates.talent = '. "$type";
            }

            if(isset($skill))
            {
                $sql .= ' AND candidates.skill = '."$skill";
            }

            if(isset($gender))
            {
                $sql .= ' AND candidates.gender = '."$gender";
            }

    $query = $this->db->query($sql);

    return $query->result_array();
```

I wanting to  the `$type`, `$skill` and `$gender` variable to passed as strings that whatever the variables contain are returned in the sql as wrapped in "" is this possible? How would I do this?

Comment: Are you using COdeIgniter or some other framework? the methods looks like so. Also based on your previous questions. If so, use $this->db->escape_string($value)

Comment: Why are people still using dynamically built queries + escaping nowadays? :/

Comment: @ThiefMaster Because we can't get rid of all the bad old PHP tutorials on the www. Same reason magic quotes always turns up in SO questions.

Comment: @Thief because it is handy and the query looks naturally.

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel: So `WHERE foo = :foo` doesn't look natural?

Comment: @Thief sure it isn't. Go try copy/paste in mysql console to debug.

Comment: You also cannot copy&paste a string containing PHP variables. So if you replace placeholders or variables.. how does it matter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm basing on how the method looks and some of your previous question, and according to this you can use
`$this->db->escape_str($value)` on those variables, so they're escaped as string no matter what type they are.

Answer (score 0):

```
' AND candidates.talent = "'. $type . '"';
```

You might want to throw in a `mysql_real_escape_string()` to properly escape the input.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if(isset($type)) {
   $sql .= ' AND candidates.talent = "'. $type . '"';
}
```

Similarly for the other two clauses.

Answer (score 0):

```
 if(isset($gender))
 {
      $gender = mysql_real_escape_string($gender);
      $sql .= " AND candidates.gender = '$gender'";
 }
```